# Android API support Real time Text Recognition and support other languages

Tags: android, ocr

Good day Sir I've been using Mobile Vision API to detect text using an Android phone camera but based on its documentation it only accepts Latin based languages do you know any API that supports real time text recognition as well as support for different languages like traditional Chinese, Japanese, etc. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

This one supports Real-Time recognition for other languages: http://rtrsdk.com However, Chinese and Japanese are only available in paid version.

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY